# Sum SQL PLUS function

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to add multiple rows to combine them into lesser rows arranged by article number with the quantity ordered

Lets say I have something like this

LigneCommande

```
|noArticle|quantity
|10       |100  
|10       |0  
|10       |0  
|20       |20    
|20       |20  
|20       |20
```

Article

```
|noArticle|Description
|10       |potato
|20       |banana
|30       |ham
```

expected results:

```
|noArticle|totalquantity
|10       |100  
|20       |60
```

My results :

```
|noArticle|totalquantity
|10       |160 
|20       |160
```

at the end 1 want 2 row with 1 the article number and two the total quantity so should be 10 ; 100 and 20 ;60

Right now I have something like this

```
SELECT Article.noArticle, SUM (quantity) AS TOTALQUANTITY
FROM LigneCommande, Article
GROUP BY  Article.noArticle
ORDER BY Article.noArticle
```

The thing is it sums all the quantity and end with 20;160 and 10;160

I'm probably missing an OVER function or something can't figure it out

Edit : Alright let me clear things up I have 2 tables one that has article number and quantity in this table called LigneCommande only the article that have some quantity higher than 0 will appear. I have another table called Article which has all the article number even if there is no quantity. At the end I want all the article number from Article and all the quantity from Ligne command the keys that combine those 2 together is noArticle ( English is not my first language sorry if I'm unclear)

Comment: Are you really intending to do a Cartesian join between the LigneCommande table and the Article table?  That seems highly unlikely.  Are you showing us just the data in the `Article` table?  If so, why are you joining to `LigneCommande` at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [rollup modifier](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets#rollup) in your group by clause:

```
SELECT Article.noArticle, SUM (quantity) AS TOTALQUANTITY
FROM Article
LEFT JOIN LigneCommande ON Article.noArticle=LigneCommande.noArticle
GROUP BY ROLLUP( Article.noArticle)
```

You can filter out the overall total in a having clause.

Comment: Seems to work pretty great can you explain the LEFT JOIN command ?

Comment: Left join is not a command, it is part of a select statement. Essetially it takes all records from the table on the left hand side of the expression and the matching data from the right hand side table. Google left join if you want to know more.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error in your sql is that you also include the LigneCommande table in your query, which seems useless. Try:

```
SELECT Article.noArticle, SUM (quantity) AS TOTALQUANTITY
FROM Article
GROUP BY  Article.noArticle
ORDER BY Article.noArticle
```

The above assumes that quantity is a column in the Article table. If this is not the case (and LigneCommande has quantity) then you need to join it accordingly to your schema (which for example might be something like the following)

```
SELECT a.noArticle, SUM (l.quantity) AS TOTALQUANTITY
FROM Article a 
Join LigneCommande l on l.noArticle = a.noArticle
GROUP BY  a.noArticle
ORDER BY a.noArticle
```